# Visual Studio Paired Editor Panes

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Is there any way to make Visual Studio have "paired" editor panes, somewhat like XCode's Assistant Editor feature? More specifically, I'd like to replicate the XCode feature of having a .cpp file's .h partner be automatically open in an adjacent editor panel. So, when a .cpp file is opened in a text editor panel (let's say, on the left of the screen), its analogous .h file will open in another panel (on the right). That way both can be edited on the same screen at the same time, without the need to manually place both files in their respective editor panes.

Hope that makes sense, I'm not really sure what terminology to use in order to search for existing solutions.